# Is there a way to validate XML using T-SQL?

Tags: .net, xml, t-sql

I'm in the process of converting a varchar(8000) field to an xml field in MSSQL 2005.
Many of the XML docs have small issues (example: degree symbol not encoded). Is there a better way to validate the XML than a Try/Catch process?

Maybe I could write a .NET Stored Procedure. What is the proper method to validate (or invalidate) an XML document in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Stored Procedure in managed code. Here  are some samples http://www.yukonxml.com/articles/sqlclr/

Answer (score 0):

So far I think it is more simple (but brute) to use the Try/Catch method. The team I am working on hasn't really started using Managed Stored Procs yet.